# I am getting a blank dynamic html table

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I am trying to create dynamic html table but the problem is that it is not displaying any data in the table. I know the query is correct because I tested the query in sql and it outputs the data. The problem I have I am guessing is the dynamic html table itself. Below is the code:

JavaScript/JQuery:

```
//javascript below will perform calculation between adding numbers between text inputs per each question
//answer for each calculation per question is stored under "Total Marks Remaining" Column
/*If a question only has one answer, then the text input under the "Marks Per Answer" column becomes
read only and displays the same number as the total marks under the "Total Marks Remaining" column
for that question*/

$(function() {   
    //alert("here");         
    var questions = $('#markstbl td[class*="_ans"]').length-1;

    //disable single entry
    for (var i=0;i<=questions;i++){   
        if($("[class*=q"+i+"_mark]").length ==1){
            var t_marks = $("[class*=q"+i+"_ans]").html();
            //alert(t_marks);
            $("[class*=q"+i+"_mark]").val(t_marks).attr("disabled","disabled");
            //$("[class*=q"+i+"_mark]").attr("disabled","disabled");
        }                    
    }

    //find each question set and add listeners
    for (var i=0;i<=questions;i++){                                     
        $('input[class*="q'+i+'"]').keyup(function(){
            var cl = $(this).attr('class').split(" ")[1]
            var questionno = cl.substring(cl.indexOf('q')+1,cl.indexOf('_'));
            var tot_marks = $(".q"+questionno+"_ans_org").val();
            //alert(tot_marks);
            var ans_t=0;
            $("[class*=q"+questionno+"_mark]").each(function(){
                var num = (isNaN(parseInt($(this).val())))?0:parseInt($(this).val());
                ans_t+=parseInt(num);                             
            });
            ans_t=tot_marks-ans_t;                             
            //alert(ans_t);
            //var fixedno = tot_marks;
            var ans = (parseInt(ans_t)<0)?tot_marks:ans_t;
            $(".q"+questionno+"_ans").val(ans);
            $(".q"+questionno+"_ans_text").html(ans);
        });
    }
});

</script>
```

PHP:

```
    <?php

if (isset($_POST['id'])) {

$_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];

}

$assessment = $_SESSION['id'];
    include('connect.php');

    $query = "SELECT q.SessionId, s.SessionName, q.QuestionId, q.QuestionContent, an.Answer, q.QuestionMarks 
    FROM Session s 
    INNER JOIN Question q ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId
    JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId AND an.SessionId = q.SessionId
    WHERE s.SessionName = ?
    ORDER BY q.QuestionId, an.Answer";

    // prepare query
    $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
    // You only need to call bind_param once
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $assessment);
    // execute query
    $stmt->execute(); 


    // This will hold the search results
    $searchQuestionId = array();
    $searchQuestionContent = array();
    $searchAnswer = array();
    $searchMarks = array();

    // Fetch the results into an array

    // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
    $stmt->bind_result($dbSessionId, $dbSessionName, $dbQuestionId, $dbQuestionContent, $dbAnswer, $dbQuestionMarks);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $searchQuestionId[] = $dbQuestionId;
        $searchQuestionContent[] = $dbQuestionContent;
        $searchAnswer[] = $dbAnswer;
        $searchMarks[] = $dbQuestionMarks;
    }?>
```

HTML:

```
<form id="Marks" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
<table border='1' id='markstbl'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class='questionth'>Question No.</th>
            <th class='questionth'>Question</th>
            <th class='answerth'>Answer</th>
            <th class='answermarksth'>Marks per Answer</th>
            <th class='noofmarksth'>Total Marks</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
    $row_span = array_count_values($searchQuestionId);
    $prev_ques = '';
    foreach($searchQuestionId as $key=>$questionId){?>
        <tbody>   
            <tr class="questiontd">
            <?php
            if($questionId != $prev_ques){?>
                <td class="questionnumtd" name="numQuestion" rowspan="<?=$row_span[$questionId]?>"><?=$questionId?> <input type="hidden" name="q<?=$questionId?>_ans_org" class="q<?=$questionId?>_ans_org" value="<?=$searchMarks[$key]?>"><input type="hidden" name="q<?=$questionId?>_ans" class="q<?=$questionId?>_ans" value="<?=$searchMarks[$key]?>"></td>
                <td class="questioncontenttd" rowspan="<?=$row_span[$questionId]?>"><?=$searchQuestionContent[$key]?> </td>
            <?php
            }else{?>
                <td class="questionnumtd" name="numQuestion" ></td>
                <td class="questioncontenttd" ></td>
            <?php
            }?>
                <td class="answertd" name="answers[]"><?=$searchAnswer[$key]?></td>
                <td class="answermarkstd">
                <input class="individualMarks q<?=$questionId?>_mark_0"  q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" />
                </td>
            <?php
            if($questionId != $prev_ques){?>
                <td class="noofmarkstd q<?=$questionId?>_ans_text"  q_group="1" rowspan="<?=$row_span[$questionId]?>"><?=$searchMarks[$key]?></td>
            <?php
            }else{?>
                <td class="noofmarkstd"  q_group="1"></td>
            <?php
            }?>
            </tr>
        <?php
        $prev_ques = $questionId;
    }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Below is the screenshot of what it is displaying:

[image: empty table]

Below is what the table should display (The Marks per Answer Column contains text inputs for each row)

[image: what table should look like]

Below is database design so you can see where the data is coming from:

**Session Table:** (Where the exam details is stored)

```
SessionId  SessionName
1          AAA
```

**Question Table:** (Where questions for each exams are stored)

```
SessionId   QuestionId       QuestionContent                Total Marks
1                 1          Name three features in a ROM        5 
1                 2          Here is a single answer             5
```

**Answer Table:** (Stores answers for each question in each exam)

```
AnswerId(auto)  SessionId QuestionId  Answer
1               1         1           A
2               1         1           B
3               1         1           D
4               1         2           True
```

**Individual_Answer Table:** (Stores each individual mark for each individual answer)

```
AnswerId   AnswerMarks
1          2
2          2
3          1
4          5
```

UPDATE:

Looking at my html code, why is it displaying the table like this below:

[image: table not displayed correctly]

Comment: I like to say I am not receiving any php errors as error report is turned on and there are no errors in error console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for missing php open tag `<?php` before `include('connect.php');`

Also avoid short tags like `<?=` and replace them with `<?php echo`

Comment: There is a <? in script, I just did not include it in code in question. Sorry

Comment: You are correct, this has now outputted the content. I have marked your answer. Can I just quickly ask you an additional question. I included an update in the question above, can I ask why the table looks like what it does in the update and not look like how it suppose to do in the screenshot I stated it should look like?

Comment: you need to check your markup..i would recommend you to ask a separate question or else it will dilute the essence of this post..

Answer (score 0):

place `<tbody>` outside the foreach loop

```
foreach($searchQuestionId as $key=>$questionId){

?>
<tbody>
```

to

```
</thead>
<tbody>
....
....

foreach($searchQuestionId as $key=>$questionId){

?>
```

Comment: I placed the tbody outside the foreach loop, still displays empty table

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is some code that is not being displayed here, perhaps it's as simple as the $assessment variable not being set, so nothing is being sent to the query?

Also, to confirm that you are actually getting the results back AND binding them OK, I'd be doing a var_dump on the arrays like searchQuestionContent to make sure they have the content you expect in them, if not you know your problem is in the query / binding data. If they do have the content you expect, then you know the problem lies in the table output.

Comment: The $assessment variable is set. I will do a var_dump on each array and see what happens and let you know

Comment: The var_dump() seems fine as it is displaying this `array(4) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(1) [2]=> int(1) [3]=> int(2) } array(4) { [0]=> string(28) "Name three features in a ROM" [1]=> string(28) "Name three features in a ROM" [2]=> string(28) "Name three features in a ROM" [3]=> string(23) "Here is a single answer" } array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "A" [1]=> string(1) "B" [2]=> string(1) "D" [3]=> string(4) "True" } array(4) { [0]=> int(5) [1]=> int(5) [2]=> int(5) [3]=> int(5) } `. So do you know what else this could mean?